# What is this velcro-like product?

Tags: wiring, cable-management

Does anyone have an idea what this product might be?

It was found it on some hired equipment, used as a cable tie / cable tidy. It is reversible and each side will stick to itself, unlike velcro.

Maybe cable tie was not its intended use?

It looks like it comes in a roll, and so could be cut to a required size.

After extensive searching we have failed to find this product, but we'd really like to purchase some.

[image: mystery product 1]

[image: mystery product 2]

Comment: Are there any markings on it at all?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Just the plain lattice.

Comment: That looks very useful...now I want some too!

Comment: I believe it is a cable tie. I seem to remember seeing it advertised. The USP is that you can undo it, unlike standard zip ties that require snippers or a knife to break.

Comment: There are releasable cable ties on the market, but Panduit has the patent, and they ask a lot of money for them.

Comment: Something used in tree nurseries?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the exact product pictured, but http://www.zhihonghk.com/cp/html/?73.html sells something that looks like it matches the functionality of sticking to itself on both sides and it looks sturdier.

[image: Double sided velcro]

I've never used the product above, but I have used [Velcro ONE-WRAP thin ties](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WB6MYM) and they work well as a cable tie and even for holding parts of a display stand together where it requires a bit of strength.  I think the green lattice product the original question asks about may have too many holes in it to be very strong and its plastic may become brittle over time, especially if exposed to UV.  On the other hand, it sort of looks like silicone which can last quite a long time.  So it really depends what it's made of.